# Reportviewer Tablix e ou Matrix Calcular valor apartir de uma celula

Tags: c#, visual-studio, relatório, reportviewer

Gostaria de sabe se teria como calcular no Repbortviewer Tablix e ou Matrix um valor a partir de um resultado de uma outra célula.
Exemplo:

Celula1 = 1; 
Celula2 = 2; 
Celula3 = Celula1 + Celula2;